# Dynamic name deployment for Firebase Functions failing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently running into problems with deploying dynamically-named Firebase Functions. What I'm basically trying to achieve is, that the Functions get named respective to the current git branch that the repository is on. The deployment is handled by a github action CI. The functions themselves are exported using `export.default` within the module files. This is my current `index.ts` file:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv"

import initiateUpdate from "./modules/initiateUpdate"
import initiateUpdateForPool from "./modules/initiateUpdateForPool"
import createPool from "./modules/createPool"

dotenv.config()
const branchName = process.env.BRANCH_NAME

const functions = {
  initiateUpdate,
  initiateUpdateForPool,
  createPool,
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(functions)) {
  if (branchName) {
    const functionName = `${branchName}-${key}`
    exports[functionName] = value
  } else {
    exports[key] = value
  }
}
```

The `process.env.BRANCH_NAME` variable is correctly defined, so don't worry about that. Firebase actually tries to deploy (create) the functions and displays the name correctly when running `firebase deploy --only functions:<<BRANCH_NAME>>`. Nevertheless, after trying to create the functions, I get the following error for every function:

```bash
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Function 'mybranch.initiateUpdateForPool' is not defined in the provided module.
Did you specify the correct target function to execute?
Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
```

Hardcoding the group name (e.g. "new"), does work, nevertheless I want the function to be named according to the current branch.

Does anyone have experience with deploying dynamically named functions? Would be very helpful to get any insight on this issue. The deployment succeeds when the BRANCH_NAME environment value is not set. So the actual exports of the functions are working as expected.

Comment: Have you checked if this link on [troubleshooting Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#global)?